# Rails 3 Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (500 Unrecognized command )

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

while sending email from the live server,

if i configure the smtp settings with gmail account it sends mail successfully,

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myhostip' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address=> "mail.gmail.com",
  :port=> 587,
  :authentication=> "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto=> false,
  :user_name=> "mymail@gmail.com",
  :password=> "password"
}
```

if i configure the smtp settings with my server details it not sending mail, instead it throws error

**Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (500 Unrecognized command)**

this is triggered during sending confirmation email for user from device.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myhostip' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address=> "mail.mydomain.com",
  :port=> 587,
  :domain=> "mydomain.com",
  :authentication=> "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto=> false,
  :user_name=> "test@mydomain.com",
  :password=> "pwd"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the port for your server is `587` ?

Comment: yes, the port for the server is 587 and by default it use postfix. I didn't make any configuration in postfix.

Comment: I resolved this by changing the config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp to config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail

Comment: the problem in setting the action_mailer.delivery_method to :sendmail is for gmail account, I am receiving the mail in gmail spam box

Answer (score 0):

You've to use ActionMaliler::Base instead of config

```
   ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings   #try this

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings   #instead of  this
```

Change your smtp code to below. It should work now.

```
      ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
         :address        => 'path_to_address_specified_by_my_hoster',
         :port           => 25,
         :domain         => 'my_domain.com',
         :authentication => :plain,
         :user_name      => 'signup@my_domain.com',
         :password       => 'password'
          }
```